# React hooks component did update with prevProps

Tags: reactjs

I was converting my react code from class to hooks

I previously had something like this

```
export default class Editor extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = this.getStateObject()
  }

  getStateObject() {
    const { page } = this.props
    return {
      label: page.label || '',
      session: page.session || false
    }
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (!_.isEqual(this.props.projects, prevProps.projects)) {
      this.setState(this.getStateObject())
    }
  }
```

When Trying to move to functional, I did something like this

```
export default function tabEditor ({page}:Page) {

  const [appPageInfo, setAppPageInfo] = useState({
      label: page.label || '',
      session: page.session || false
  })
  
 /* Equivalence in hooks
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (!_.isEqual(this.props.projects, prevProps.projects)) {
      this.setState(this.getStateObject())
    }
  }
*/


  const handleOnClickUpdate = () => {
    updateMobileAppPage(Object.assign({}, page, appPageInfo))
    close()
  }
```

but I am unable to determine the equivalence of `componentDidUpdate` in React hooks.

Comment: I'm in the similar situation, have you found a solution yet? @hardik khanna

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `useEffect` hook add pass it the `projects` props as dependency like this :

```
useEffect(() => {
   // Whatever code you want to run if props.projects change
}, [props.projects]);
```

Answer (score 0):

To mimic componentDidUpdate in Hooks, you make use of useEffect and then pass in the conditional parameter with which useEffect will run whenever the parameter changes. Example below

```
useEffect(() => {
.......
//This useEffect will re-run whenever the parameter in the square bracket updates/changes.
}, [parameter])
```